# Implementing `split`

Tags: haskell, reinventing-the-wheel

I implemented the `split` function in Haskell:

```
split :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> [[a]]
split _ [] = []
split x ys = f : split x rest 
  where (f, rest) = break (== x) (dropWhile (== x) ys)
```

Note that I'm calling `dropWhile (== x)` since `break`'s second-tuple value will include the "broken on" value.

example:

```
*Main> break (== 'a') "dogacactus"
("dog","acactus")
```

**Testing**

```
*Main> split2 '3' "123aaaBBB3"
["12","aaaBBB",""]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally it looks good, at least to an Haskell beginner like me.
I find the use of `dropWhile` to be a bit confusing. I admit I had to read your comment to understand why you used it.

I think it could also have introduced a bug. What is the expected behaviour for `split ',' ",,"`?
Your code returns `[""]` but I would expect `["","",""]`. Was your behaviour intended?

This solution fixed the issue.

```
split :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> [[a]]
split _ [] = []
split separator ys = f : (split separator (dropSeparator separator rest))
  where (f, rest) = break (== separator) ys

dropSeparator :: Eq a => a ->  [a] -> [a]
dropSeparator _ [] = []
dropSeparator separator (x:xs) = if x == separator then xs else x:xs
```

I prefer using meaningful variable names, such as `separator`, even if I'm not sure if it is idiomatic Haskell. Ditto for the parentheses and the introduction of the helper function.

Comment: thank you for letting me know that my usage of `dropWhile` was both confusing and incorrect! Initially I wanted to do something like `where (f, _:rest) = ... `, but that would fail to match for `[]`.